# Cannot get output for more than one user defined digit

Tags: python, list, input, indexing

def main():

Need the code to ask the user a number and print out number in words digit by digit.
Ex. Input: 473
Output: four seven three

```
numbers = ["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]

n = eval(input('Please input a number: '))
print('You typed a number: ',n)
print('The number in words: ', numbers[n])
```

Cannot get code here to print out more than one digit. I have tried a few for loops and always get the error message with my index

main()

Comment: Could you reword your question?

Answer (score 0):

Because your list has 10 items and it can not find index for example 324
so you should split your number into digits and try it for each digit.

```py
numbers = ["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]

n = int(input('Please input a number: '))
print('You typed a number: ',n)
print('The number in words: ', end="")
for char in str(n):
    print(numbers[int(char)], end=" ")
print()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Per my previous comment I was acclimated to using eval in my functions as the prior problems required calculations and didn't consider the consequence.  Thanks a ton for incorporating my code with a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to access an element in an array(your array only have 10 elements, so works fine for n<=10) that doesn't exist. You need to extract the digits, and try for every digit.

Comment: Thank you! I got used to eval and did not even consider the consequence of it wanting strings. That is super helpful

Answer (score 0):

you can put numbers in a dictionary
numbers = {'0': 'zero', '1': 'one', '2': 'two', etc...}

then loop throw the user's string:

for number in n:
print(numbers[number] + " ", end='')

Answer (score 0):

here is version that uses a list comprehension:

```
numbers = ["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]
inp = input()
print(" ".join([numbers[int(dig)] for dig in inp]))
```